# Looking for the right size for a box in which to store my chess set

Tags: chess-set, equipment

So I have this nice chess set that was gifted to me some time ago. The thing is that I don't have a proper box for the pieces (the set came in a card box, good for transportation but not for everyday storage).

<s>I just had the idea that someone with a set similar to mine could measure their box and give me the numbers. You know, it's easy finding/building a box in which the pieces have room enough, but I'd like the proper dimensions for using just the precise space.</s>

The sizes of the main pieces are:

```
king 10cm (4 inches)
rook 5.5cm (2 inches)
pawn 4cm (1.5 inches)
```

What would be the right size for a box in which to store my chess set?

Actually I realized that I don't need the measures of a chess set *exactly* like mine. Since the sizes of the pieces and the box are proportional, **I just need the sizes of a couple of pieces (say king, rook and pawn) and the size of the box in which those pieces fit**. The it's just a simple rule of three.

Also, it's a good idea -provided by [Laska](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/8201/laska)- to use cardboard for testing.

Comment: I can understand this is not quite a standard question for this forum, but in the "What topics can I ask about here?" section it's mentioned that one can ask questions about "physical items such as chessboards, pieces, and clocks."

Ok, I'm asking actually about the size of a _box_ to store my pieces, but it's not like a totally unrelated topic. Also, the "such as" should be understood as a not closed list.

Comment: Make a quick cardboard or paper box to see what the rough dimensions need to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I figured out a way to solve it. Since I realized I don't need a chess set exactly like mine, but just the info of any chess set (pieces and box) and then use a rule of three to scale it to my pieces set, I made a search on Google and found these results:

- https://www.chesshouse.com/products/classic-chess-set-and-box-combo
- https://www.rrgames.com/druke-walnut-box-with-wooden-chess-pieces.html

Probably more can be found, but I'm pretty sure that two will be enough.

Also, I'll use cardboard for testing till I get the optimal size and build the final box in wood, DMF or whatever material I choose.